# IE gives “Function expected” error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this piece of code which executes when pasting images. It works on chrome and firefox without throwing any error.

```
            var file;
            for (var index in items) {
                var item = items[index];
                if (item.kind === 'file') {
                    var blob = item.getAsFile();

                    var newFileName = angular.copy(blob.name);
                    if (blob.type == "image/png") {
                        var last4 = newFileName.slice(-4)
                        if (last4 != ".png") newFileName += ".png";
                    }
                    if (blob.type == "image/jpeg") {
                        var last4 = newFileName.slice(-4);
                        if (last4 != ".jpg") {
                            newFileName += ".jpg";
                        }
                    }
                    file = new File([blob], newFileName, { type: blob.type, lastModified: Date.now()});
                }
            }
```

In IE i got the error `"Function expected"` exactly when the line `file = new File([blob], newFileName, { type: blob.type, lastModified: Date.now()});` gets executed. 
When i read the [documentation for that error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/misc/function-expected) i can't figure out why i'm getting that error as i'm not trying to call the instantiated object as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't support File constructor https://caniuse.com/#search=File

To handle files in IE you should use IE File Api https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh673542(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: i need to upload the file to server , is there any alternative to the File constructor for IE ? in the IE File Api i can't find how to create a file from a blob for an image

Comment: @Bardelman File is inherite from blob so you can try using blob or use a File polyfill library like this https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie#getting-started